# Why is json.Marshal seemingly producing an array of ints?

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Go language and I've hit my first stumbling block with this simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type MyStructure struct {
    Integer int    `json:"integer"`
    Label   string `json:"label"`
}

func main() {
    ms := &MyStructure{9001, "over9000"}
    msjson, _ := json.Marshal(ms)
    fmt.Println(msjson)  // expect: {"integer": 9001, "label": "over9000"}
}
```

My output is as follows:  `[123 34 105 110 116 101 103 101 114 34 58 57 48 48 49 44 34 108 97 98 101 108 34 58 34 111 118 101 114 57 48 48 48 34 125]`

I'm clearly missing something obvious; could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your output is exactly what you expect. Note that `json.Marshal` returns a slice of bytes and printing a slice of bytes, well: It prints a slice of bytes. `string(msjson)` converts to a string which might meet your expectations when printed. Sidenote: Use `fmt.Printf("%#v", msjson)` to see the type which is helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It produces a byte slice (ref : http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal), use `string(msjson)` to get the string.

Also never ignore errors, it bites you back whenever you least expect it.

```
fmt.Println(string(msjson))
// or
fmt.Printf("%s\n", msjson) //shamelessly taken from @dustin's comment
```

Comment: Ah okay!  I'm still getting used to the Go way of doing things!  Thank you!

Comment: "Also never ignore errors"... Shouldn't it be `_, err := fmt.Println(string(msjson))` then? :)

Comment: Printf with %s is the easiest easy to print a string.  You don't need to make another copy as a string first.

Comment: Wellllll the error from `Println` would be rather obvious, nothing will be printed :-p

Comment: Ignoring the error from fmt.Print is the only exception: primarily because there's often little you can do if you can't print anyway.